# Lower Right white box

Tags: 12.10, .desktop, unity-previews

In Ubuntu 12.10 there is a small type box that appears in the lower right when I just start typing from the desktop.
What is it? and how am I supposed to use it?
Ric

Answer (score 0):

The box that appears is a "type ahead" feature. It will automatically highlight items on your desktop that match your input.
In example: [image]

As I typed "egg" it matched the first item with that filename.

Answer (score 0):

It is used for quick searching and access to files and folders.

You can type any key on keyboard, the first file(alphabetically) starting with that character will be highlighted.You can press enter to open the file/folder.

You can use up and down arrow keys to surf between all files/folders starting with that character.